# SQL masking on reports

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using SQL Server 2008 SR1, Report Builder 2.0
I have searched all sorts of sites regarding masking but struggle to make it work correctly.  I wish to mask all but the last 4 digits of the SSN
I’ve tried several changes with `=Right(Fields!ssn.value,4, “NameInfo”)`
But I get an error due to changing it from `=First` to `Right`
Just not quite sure how to go about doing it correctly to achieve a mask

There is a Textbox5 with the expression:

```
=First(Fields!ssn.Value,"NameInfo")
```

One of my datasets is NameInfo and the query for the dataset:

```
SELECT nm.FullName2 
, nm.ssn
, nm.dob
, nm.SexDesc
FROM jw50_Name AS nm
WHERE NameID = @NameID
```

When I modify either the expression or try to include in the dataset query all I generate are errors.  Obviously am new to SQL and hoping someone might have a suggestion to help mask the ssn on the report - thank you for time

Answer (score 2):

> I wish to mask all but the last 4 digits of the SSN

Considering that your SSN value is of 10 digit (for example), you can use string functions `SUBSTRING()` and `REPLICATE()` to get this done like

```
SELECT REPLICATE('X',6) + SUBSTRING(SSN_Field, 7,4) as SSN
FROM table1;
```

Comment: I think the OP want's to display last... four mask first 6... so `REPLICATE('X',6) + SUBSTRING(SSN_Field, 7, 4) as SSN`

Comment: @xQbert, Thank You. That's absolutely correct. I misunderstood the sentence.

Comment: SSN would either be 9 or 11 digits depending on whether it includes the '-'s. substring on fixed positions would only be appropriate if all SSN's had the same formatting.  but the general use of replicate is appropriate

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  I still struggle though.  I believe the suggestions would be inserted somehow into the dataset query?  And not the textbox expression...I'm learning and have a long way to go...thank you again

Comment: @Terry, Yes it's a sql query (strictly SQL). No idea though how you will club it to report builder but shouldn't be difficult. You will have to figure it out but masking idea you can use in your report builder query as well.

Comment: the digits are 11 and the report displays ssn as 123-45-6789

Comment: thanks for the responses, I'll keep fiddling with it - in the report builder query for the dataset

Comment: Got it working, this is how it ended up:                                                       SELECT nm.FullName2 
 , 'XXX-XX-' + right(nm.ssn,4)as ssn
 , nm.dob
 , nm.SexDesc
FROM jw50_Name AS nm
WHERE NameID = @NameID